# Multiscale morphological dilation and erosion

Tags: multiscaleimage, mathematical-morphology

Can anyone please specify what is meant by multiscale morphological filtering ? I understand the basic concepts of dilation and erosion. But in multiscale filtering, a scaled structuring function is being used. What does the term scaled mean ?

Please find more relevant information here : [Please check link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.5379&rep=rep1&type=pdf). I want to apply this structuring element in matlab coding but cannot do so. Please can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www1.i2r.a-star.edu.sg/~wydong/papers/ijep.pdf) the multiscale operator is described as:

***F(x,s1,s2) = (f-s1)+s2***

where *f(x)* is the original function and *s1(x)* is the structure function. Apparently, erosion and
dilation with different scales can filter positive and negative noises more perfectly.This operation satisfies
the four quantification principles of morphological filter. (*from paper*)

This operator is known in the Morphology community as an [**Alternating Sequential Filter**](http://cmm.ensmp.fr/~serra/cours/pdf/en/ch4en.pdf), which basically performs filtering using a alternating series of *dilations and erosions* or *openings and closings* of increasing radii on the same image. This series of radii for the given structuring function can be decided based on the structure of the object/detail to be extracted or filtered. One can note that there are two different structuring elements s1 and s2 used to decide different scales for the erosions and dilations. This [Matlab chain](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/270818) discusses on how to test it.